# How to parse nested data results in table using foreach loop

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I'm trying to use curl to parse and display results in a table from DPLA API. I figured I would use a foreach loop to do this, but I'm having a problem getting to the nested data. What am I missing?

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.dp.la/v2/items?q=weasels&api_key=mypersonalkey");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$json_response = curl_exec($ch);
$myArray = json_decode($json_response, true);
curl_close($ch);
?>
    <h2>Part 1</h2> 
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>creator</th>
            </tr>
<?php
        foreach ($myArray as $post){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$post[title]}</td>";
            echo "<td>$post[creator]</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<pre>";
         }
?>
```

Now, I'm fairly new to php and took a class to learn more. I have been studying for a couple months online, but I could use some additional help. I've reviewed the php doc site and api.dp.la site, but still feel a little lost.

I would like to see results for 1 of the many results. Return 1 title and creator.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [complex curly syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex).

If you want to get one of the many, perhaps you could check one of the values from post using an `if`. If the if statement can match more than 1 value and you only want the first one you find you can use `break` to get out of the loop.

You might update your to to for example:

```
foreach ($myArray as $post){
    if ($post["title"] === "my title") {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>{$post["title"]}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$post["creator"]}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<pre>";
    }
}
```

Note to put the keynames `title` and `creator` between quotes.

Comment: Thanks! I ultimately used print_r to break down the nesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($myArray['docs'] as $post) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo($post['sourceResource']['creator'][0]);
            echo "<td>";
            echo($post['sourceResource']['description'][0]);
            echo "</tr>";
            break;
```

Comment: This ended up being the best way to resolve the foreach loop.